# How to add the result of a quake entry index to a new list?

Tags: java, arraylist

What is the variable type of quakeData.get(bigIndex)? How do I add quakeData.get(bigIndex) to my new list? I plan on passing a substring with each iteration to find the Largest quake how should I go about that?

I have also been using the .add() and it hasn't been working. Also, the x value is incorrect because I do not know what the variable type is.

```
public ArrayList<QuakeEntry>getLargest(ArrayList<QuakeEntry>quakeData,int howMany){
    ArrayList<QuakeEntry> answer = new ArrayList<QuakeEntry>();
    int bigIndex=indexOfLargest(quakeData);
    x=quakeData.get(bigIndex);

    // I do not understand what the data type I am getting back and I do not 
    currently know how to add it to my new Arraylist
    answer=answer.set(0,x);"

   // I will be adding a for loop and use variable k to replace 0 to get the 2nd, 3rd, 4th,etc highest by passing in a substring with each   
   // iteration


return answer;
}
```

Comment: `.set()` method will not add a new value, it will replace the current one 
if you do need to add a value  you need to use `.add()`

Comment: It would be better to not put logic into get... method, it should be simple getter. More useful will be use calculateLargest() or determineLargest() - or something like that name

Comment: Hi so I have been using the .add() method and it was not working. Knowing the value type of  quakeData.get(bigIndex) would be really helpful so I could add it to my new arrayList answer.

Comment: What IDE are you using? In the case of IntelliJ, just place the cursor in the `get` of `quakeData.get(...)` and hit `Ctrl+Q` to get a quick documentation of the method

Comment: I am using the blue j environment